# Add a newline to swagger output

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, swagger

I am using `swagger-jersey2-jaxrs` version `1.5.15`. I am on `swagger-ui 3.0.9`. I added a description to a header using @SwaggerDefinition annotation and tags (as the description parameter is now deprecated). The code goes like:

```
@Api(tags = { "Hello World" })
@SwaggerDefinition(tags = { @Tag(name = "Hello World", description = 
    "Description about world: " + "  \n" +
    "1. Hello " + "\n" +
    "2. World " + "<br>" 
 )})
```

By using this, I was able to add a description to the "Hello World" header. My question is how should I add a newline for every point. I tried the following but failed:

1. Adding `"\n"` or `"<br>"` to string. `\n"` doesn't reflect a
   newline while `"<br>"` just adds the string `"<br>"` to the string
   that is rendered.
2. I tried to use `System.lineSeparator()` and
   `System.getProperty("line.separator")` as well but that gives the
   error "The value for annotation attribute Tag.description must be a
   constant expression".

Swagger shows a newline when the first method above is used when using the `notes` parameter for the other annotations (doesn't work with @Api), any workaround to using that instead to get the newline?

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: It's just a guess, but did you try "\\n"?

Comment: @Daniel Yep, just tried. Adds a '\n' to the string rendered :/

Comment: Next try: Use "\n\n". You need a blank line between the two paragraphs.
Have a look at: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#lines

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try scaping the lower/greater, for example: `&lt;br /&gt;`

Comment: In swagger-ui 2.2.3 seemed to be a bug regarding linebreaks. Which version do you use?

Comment: Not sure about swagger-ui, using 1.5.15 for swagger-core. Precisely swagger-jersey2-jaxrs version 1.5.15.

Comment: @canillas that doesn't work :/

Comment: Weird that '/n' for newline works for the `notes` parameter but not for `description`

Comment: Using swagger-ui 3.0.9 (updated the question).

Answer (score 27):

Use double "`<br>`" or "`\n`", swagger will show the text in the next line.
For e.g:

`@SwaggerDefinition(tags = { @Tag(name = "Hello World", description = 
    "Description about world: \n\n" +
    "1. Hello \n\n" +
    "2. World <br><br>" 
 )})`

Comment: Thanks for this, I couldn't find any other site or Swagger documentation that points to this. Do you know more about this behaviour, like why Swagger accepts double `<br>` or `\n`, but not single?

Comment: add \n\n helps to generate new line in pdf. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following:

```
@SwaggerDefinition(tags = { @Tag(name = "Hello World", description =
    "Description about world: <br /> " +
            "1. Hello <br /> " +                  //With <br />, not  <br>
            "2. World ")})
```

It works for me, it gives the following result, with line breaks:

[image]

Have fun !

Comment: Thanks for the answer, doesn't work for me, it just prints `<br />` with the text. Which `swagger-ui` version are you on? I am using version 3.0.9.

Comment: Hi, I'm using swagger-ui:2.1.2
Maybe you can change the swagger version you are using, at least for testing ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sure, I'll upgrade my swagger and check (y).

Comment: same result as @harshit-sh. Any updates on this one?

Answer (score 3):

Simply add

```
<br><br>
```

example :

```
  /autoComplete:
    post:
      tags:
        - AutoComplete Service
      summary: Various AutoComplete Services 
      description: > List 
        1. Name <br><br>
        2. Teams  <br><br>
```